# How to extract any resource file from APK using the Androguard?

Tags: python, android, apk, androguard

I want to extract any file like libraries(so files) and images(app icon, background image, ETC) using the Androguard.
I know The a.get_app_icon() and a.get_files_information() method returns paths, but how can I extract them as real file using the Androguard?

Answer (score 0):

Use `a.zip.extract(filename)` to extract that file.